# Is it better to start negotiating for a bigger raise before or after your annual performance review?

Tags: salary, raise, performance-reviews

I am one of the most senior software engineers in my division.  Our company has the typical big company "the budget for raises is 3%" finite pie stance.  I got promoted last year but that only added a little bit to the 3%.  At this point I am way underpaid compared to my peers at other companies and to my worth to my company.  Additionally, they are desperate, can't find good programmers to hire, and the rest of us are all overworked.  I feel like I should be able to demand more than 3% and  get it.  Should I say this going into reviews or wait to see what they give me and then try to negotiate outside of the "3%" process?

Answer (score 4):

> Should I say this going into reviews or wait to see what they give me
> and then try to negotiate outside of the "3%" process?

It depends on how the process works in your company.

Most places where I worked, you would have the opportunity to "negotiate" for a bigger raise *during* the process. That allowed time for the manager to go back and decide how the raise pie was to be divided. The raises were handed out after the performance review was completed.

But if in your company, the performance review is the time when your raise is communicated to you, then you should make your case *beforehand*. And in that scenario, waiting until afterwards would likely be problematic, since the department's "slice of the pie" has already been divided and communicated out.

Comment: Negotiating a for a bigger slice of the finite pie is just taking money away from your coworkers to maybe get 4% instead of 3%.  The issue is how to get a real raise that goes beyond the annual review policy and takes inflation and market conditions into account.

Answer (score 2):

In today's economy a 3% "raise" is effectively a cut in pay since inflation over the last year has exceeded that by a significant margin.

That being said, companies are not in the "charity" business even if they are charities.  They pay employees what they think they are worth and for the most part.  What this means is that things like "I deserve more money" or "I need more money because my bills are higher" are likely to be unsuccessful.  They also don't really care how hard you work.  They care about your results.

The better approach is to prepare yourself with two things:

1. Your contributions to the company and especially when these are related to company performance.  If you can tie your work into company profits that's a big deal.
2. Your worth in the marketplace.  This is a bit more difficult but sources like salary surveys and job postings can help.  Obviously the best evidence is a competitive job offer but I've never seen those work effectively in the long term.  You often gain a short term increase at the expense of longer term increases and promotions.  I'd only do this if you really want to end up working at the other company.

If you do your homework and that does not result in an increase that you feel is appropriate, then it's time to move on.  Your company does not believe in paying people what they are worth.  Some may have adopted the philosophy that the current job market is transitive and they hope to wait it out.  That approach may be successful, who knows?

Comment: This doesn't seem to come close to answering the question.